# How to increase performance for nearest neighbour query using a multipoint? (Boost Geometry)

Tags: geometry, c++, rtree, boost.geometry

The following function gets the nearest point in an rtree to a multipoint geometry. I'd like the performance of the function to be better. Is there any way to make it faster?

```
TimingLink* JourneyPattern::getClosestFromTimingLink(multipoint g,int maxFromSequence) {
    std::vector<LinkPair> result_n;
    linkFromTree.query(bgi::nearest(g, 1)  &&
        bgi::satisfies([maxFromSequence](LinkPair const& v) {
            return ((v.second)->fromSequence < maxFromSequence);
        }), std::back_inserter(result_n));
    if (!result_n.empty())
        return result_n[0].second;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

The purpose of the function is to find a point in the rtree linkFromTree that is closest to the multipoint g and whose fromSequence is less than maxFromSequence. linkFromTree is an rtree [created using the packing algorithm](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/rtree_iterator__iterator_.html) and it usually contains about 100 points. The multipoint g will also contain about 100 points.

The slow part seems to be using a multipoint (g) to do the nearest neighbour query, as I have a similar function that uses a point instead and it is much faster (average 20x faster).

Comment: Is the single-point N times faster than a N-point multipoint? There are a **lot** of variables the you haven't addressed, but I wouldn't expect multipoint performance to be optimal.

Comment: Single point is about 0.5ms to run, so it's possible I guess. The problem is I need to compare two sets of points. Is there a good alternative to using a multipoint? Also, what other variables should I be thinking of?

Comment: If you want to alter the question, please use the **edit** button. There are too many to type on this device, but: number of features, extent of features, number of features within extent, relation of extent to overall extent, definition of multipoint eqivalence, number of cores, number of threads, CPU GHz,...

Comment: Ah I see. The absolute time taken isn't really important, just that I'd like to make it run faster. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use a kdtree instead of rtree. I used [nanoflann](https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann). It runs about 20x faster.